# How to manually update a mongodb collection from the command line in cloud9-ide?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, cloud9-ide

I'm in a meteor/mongodb environment and I'm trying to add a key/value to the users collection and check that the updated data now exists on the client.

In the cloud9 ide, on the command line, I enter

```
db.users.find({emails : { $elemMatch : { "address":"colm@1.com" }}});
```

This finds the corresponding entry.
Then,in cloud9 ide, I do

```
db.users.findAndModify({ query:{emails : { $elemMatch : { "address":"colm@1.com" }}}, update:{$set:{ "roles":"VIP"}}});
```

This works to the extent that when I repeat the db.user.find.. command above I now see the "roles":"VIP" at the same level as the "emails" key.

I restart the server and login to the website as colm@1.com.
In the console on the browser I type in 
`Meteor.user().emails[0].address` and it replies colm@1.com

However when I type in 
`Meteor.user().roles` it tells me undefined.
it looks as though the db change I make on the console in cloud9-ide, doesn't get propagated to the client ? Is this normal, or what am I doing wrong ?

P.S. I'm also confused by the existence of local and meteor databases. I believe that I am in meteor db by default but I'm not entirely sure about this.

best regards / Colm

Comment: If you removed `insecure` package you should set proper rights to update docs. So it may look like you changed something, but it only applies to the client.

Comment: Have you removed `autopublish`?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I need to learn more about the  pub/sub thing, and also perhaps use the alanning:roles package, rather than reinventing the wheel.